# How do I know my OpenId Identity URL?

Tags: openid

I am trying to run an example from OpenId.  Here it the url of their example:

http://www.comehike.com/openid-php-openid-782224d/examples/consumer/

They ask me for my identity url.  But I have no idea what it is supposed to be :)

How do I know what to enter in there?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to signup here [https://www.myopenid.com/signup](https://www.myopenid.com/signup)
to get an openid url.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many services can support OpenID.  Depending on which one you choose to use, the URL will be different.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenID#OpenID_Providers) Wikipedia entry for a list of the most common providors' OpenID URLs.  Note that some of the URLs depend on your username or some other characteristic of your account with that providor.

Comment: Huh? This answer totally doesn't make sense for what I asked.  Or maybe I am misunderstanding?

Comment: The idea behind OpenID is that you can log into numerous websites with a single OpenID account.  However, there are many different types of OpenID accounts: you can have an OpenID account from Google, Yahoo, AOL, etc.  Depending on what kind you have, you use a different identity URL.  For example, do you have an account with Google?  If so, use this identity URL in the link you provided: `https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id`.

Comment: I think I understand...I just tried this: https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/alex.genadinik@gmail.com (at the end is my gmail address ..but it didn't seem to work.  What is the o8 you have in the url?

Comment: Do not modify the URL - put it in the form exactly as I have it above.  You don't need to include your account name.

Comment: @cheeken: What if an user enter a arbitrary openid account, how do I know the identity url? Do I have to keep a list of identity url of a list of openid provider in advance? No way to find them automatically?